# webDriverException "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service ./webdrivers/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running a simple python based selenium webdriver script for geckodriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
geckodriver_path = "./webdrivers/geckodriver"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver_path)
driver.get("https://dev.to")
driver.find_element_by_id("nav-search").send_keys("Selenium")
```

after execution showing Warning message along with Exception

```
/<path>/demo.py:3: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver_path)
```

And the exception is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service ./webdrivers/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

The environment which is being used
python(3.9.2)
selenium(4.1.0)
geckodriver(0.24.0)
firefox(87.0 64-bit)

Output of geckodriver.log

```
error: Found argument '--websocket-port' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    geckodriver [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]

For more information try --help
```

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium after version 4, it's recommended to use Services, still don't know why, but if someone will find, it would be great to know.

To resolve issue you could try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FXService
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox


search_by = 'xpath'
search_path = "//div[@id='header-search']/form/div/div/input"    

driver_path = './webdrivers/geckodriver'
driver = Firefox(service=FXService(driver_path))

driver.get("https://dev.to")
driver.find_element('xpath', div_path).send_keys("Selenium")
```

And, the reason with `exit code 1` could be related with geckodriver version, take a look on compatibility list here: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html

Hope this will be helpful!

Comment: It works after giving absolute path for variable geckodriver_path, also update geckodriver version to latest 0.30.0

Answer (score 0):

It works after giving absolute path for variable geckodriver_path, also update geckodriver version to latest one. (currently it is 0.30.0 which is compatible with firefox 87.0 64-bit )